# Visual Studio showing blank tab ?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

In my VS 2013 I have a file as GuestMasterPage.master
It shows in the tab above with "GuestMasterPage.master:2" 
It displays blank and I cannot edit it in VS.

I can edit the file externally in notepad but here in VS 2013 it just displays blank. I've clicked design view , markup view and still it shows nothing. 
Other tabs like Home.aspx and every other work fine. 
Any help with ":2" thing ? IDK what it means.

Comment: do you have resharper?

Comment: It resolved automatically. I think there was some problem loading up the project files. I re-opened VS as administrator quite a few times and voila! That did it. Thanks.

Comment: same problem with 2015 community, I did what you did, and solved. thanks.